# continue reading data after a pause of one second

Tags: go

I am using curl to get data from an endpoint and piping it into a program. The main function of the program reads the data like this

```
reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
var buf bytes.Buffer
line, err := reader.ReadString(`\n`)
for {
  if err != nil{
     buf.WriteString(line)
     break
   }
  buf.WriteString(line)
}
var data Memstats
err = json.Unmarshal(buf.Bytes(), &data)
```

Everything works fine until here. However, my ultimate goal is to curl the endpoint repeatedly for a period of time like this so that program reads N number of JSON blobs arriving at intervals of N time.

```
for i in {1..10}; do curl localhost:6000/debug/vars | ./myprogram; sleep 1; done
```

Data of the same structure will arrive after each curl to the endpoint. Therefore, I had to move the data reading code into a function `readStdIn` that I will repeatedly call until the curl stops sending data, and each time my program receives json data, I'd unmarshall it into a struct and add it to a slice. To repeatedly call readStdIn, I am using a for loop, and to read the data within readStdIn, I am also using a for loop. The `readStdIn` function is never completing. Why not?

**main function**

```
for{
 reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
 h.readStdIn(reader)
 time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
 var err error
 //check to see if curl sent more data,  if not I break out of main function and continue on with program and hopefully an array full of Memstats
 newbytes, err := reader.ReadByte()
 if err != nil{
   break
 }

}
```

**readStdIn function**

```
func (rt *Graph)readStdIn(reader *bufio.Reader){
 var buf bytes.Buffer
 line, err := reader.ReadString('\n')
 for {
  if err != nil{
     if err == io.EOF{
        buf.WriteString(line)
        break
     }else{
       fmt.Println(err.Error())
       os.Exit(1)
     }
  }
 }
 buf.WriteString(line)
}
var data Memstats
err = json.Marshal(buf.Bytes(), &data)
rt.Memstats = append(rt.Memstats, &record)
}
```

Comment: How are you running the curl and piping it? Are you running curl repeatedly, or are you running it in a script?

Comment: Calling curl in a loop from your shell does not mean you need to have another loop in your code, it calls your program again each time. Unrelatedly, in your new code you are discarding the `reader` after each iteration, and wrapping `Stdin` in a new `bufio.Reader`, which may lose buffered data

Comment: "The readStdIn function is never completing" --- why do you think so?

Comment: @BurakSerdar I'm running it in the terminal like it says in the op `while sleep 1; do curl localhost:6000/debug/vars | ./myprogram; done`

Comment: @zerkms I don't know. I also can't tell if you're being sarcastic, since I'm not supposed to wildly speculate if I don't know the reason for aproblem, I assuming you maybe are being sarcastic? Anyways, the code in the readStdIn function used to be in the `main` func (as it says at the top of the OP) and `for` loop did a break when the buffer stopped reading, so I expected the code, once moved into `readStdIn` to break the for loop eventually. Sorry if this is a newbie question

Comment: Your program and curl runs once for every iteration. When curl stops sending data, you should exit, so the next iteration can run. You cannot collect data from multiple runs of curl this way, because you are running your program for each invocation of curl.

Comment: "I assuming you maybe are being sarcastic?" --- no, I'm very much not. My point is - from your _provided_ code its impossible to tell that your `readStdIn` never completes. So you either run not what you provided, or otherwise it would be a hint to you - that you're making an assumption that is not valid.

Comment: Does the [json package streaming example](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#example-Decoder.Decode-Stream) work for you where the decoder is initialized with os.Stdin?

Comment: @CeriseLimon the example in the documentation is for one array of json data. (I know how to read that with Bufio.NewReader or with json.Decode and then convert into a Go object. That's not the problem.) The problem is how I read one array after another (N number of times) arriving after an interval of N time. That's why I moved the code into `ReadStdIn` func and tried to call that repeatedly.

Comment: @JImB I updated the unix command with the curl request, but I think you made it clear to me that it's impossible to do what I'm trying to do. I have to call curl multiple times to get the data sent multiple times, but there's no way for the program to keep track of each successive curl call since the program starts over each time? Is there a way to call curl multiple times and have the program run once?

Comment: @BurakSerdar I think I just understood your comment now. See my comment above this comment.

Comment: What you're trying to do wouldve been much easier if you simply fetched data from the URL within your program instead of curl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### For parsing JSON

You also can use scanner, via having custom function or changing bash script. But I believe both are more complicated than below code.

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Start")
    decoder := json.NewDecoder(os.Stdin)
    for {
        var u User
        err := decoder.Decode(&u)

        if errors.Is(err, io.EOF) {
            fmt.Println("End")
            break
        }

        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Can not decode into json", err)
            continue
        }

        fmt.Println(u)
    }
}

type User struct {
    UserId int    `json:"userId"`
    Id     int    `json:"id"`
    Title  string `json:"title"`
}
```

```bash
function repeatedCurl() {
  for i in $(seq 1 3); do
    # sleep 1 # optional you can emit
    curl -s "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/$i"
  done
}

repeatedCurl | ./foo
```

### For newline delimeted data

```golang
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Start")
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin))
    for scanner.Scan() {
        fmt.Println(scanner.Text())
    }
    fmt.Println("End")
}
```

It works with both creating new instance of program (like your example) and normal pipe usage.

#### Using same pipe

```bash
function repeatedDateEcho() {
  while sleep 1; do
   echo "$(date)"
  done
}

repeatedDateEcho | ./myprogram
```

Output:

```
Start
Thu Jan 18 22:59:31 +03 2024
Thu Jan 18 22:59:32 +03 2024
Thu Jan 18 22:59:33 +03 2024
Thu Jan 18 22:59:34 +03 2024
```

#### Using different pipe (new instance every time)

`while sleep 1; do echo "$(date)" | ./myprogram; done`
Output:

```
Start
Thu Jan 18 22:58:46 +03 2024
End
Start
Thu Jan 18 22:58:47 +03 2024
End
```

Comment: I don't think this solves my problem because my program is receiving json data, does `scanner.Scan()` scan to the end of the json blob? and start back at the beginning when the next json blob arrives?   does `Scanner.Text()` work with json blobs? I have to unmarshall the json into a struct each time it arrives.

Comment: You're right I didn't test for json, updated the answer. The problem was scanner wants newline, but curl didn't give. Your endpoints may return multiline JSON's which will break the newline part. Simplest approach is using decoder.

Answer (score 2):

Use this command to pipe the output of multiple curl invocations to your program:

```
for i in {1..10}; do curl localhost:6000/debug/vars; echo; sleep 1; done | ./myprogram
```

The `echo` command ensures that the JSON documents are separated by whitespace. You can omit the command if the server adds whitespace to the end of the response or if the root level value in the JSON document is an object, array or string.

Follow the encoding/json Decoder [example](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#example-Decoder) to read the stream of JSON documents:

```
dec := json.NewDecoder(os.Stdin)
for {
    var data Memstats
    if err := dec.Decode(&data); err == io.EOF {
        break
    } else if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err) // change to handle error as appropriate for your applicatin.
    }
    rt.Memstats = append(rt.Memstats, &data)
}
// The program continues here at the end of the stream.
```